# swift uidatePicker pass as arguements not working properly

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, uidatepicker

i am stuck in situation i have to pass a uidatepicker to a cell class. the cell class contains 14 textfields and datepicker will be used as inputview to select to and from time for whole week. the thing is when i directly initialize it in cell class. it gets initialized 14 times and thats too much costly task. but while passing as arguement it replicate the selected time to all the textfield instead of that specific one. i tried to use tags and some other ways as well but no luck. how to handle the situation that it will not impact applicatio performancee .any help regarding this will be appriciated.thankyou

Code:

```
lazy var fromDatePicker: UIDatePicker = {
     let fromDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    fromDatePicker.datePickerMode = .time
    fromDatePicker.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US") as Locale
    fromDatePicker.minuteInterval = 30
    if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
        fromDatePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
     return fromDatePicker
 }()

cell.configureCellForEmployee(with:viewModel.profileDataSource, index: indexPath.row, fromDatePicker: fromDatePicker)
```

Comment: Show.Your.Code.

Comment: updated.please check

Comment: If you have multiple cells you do need multiple pickers. It's less expensive than you think because only the visible cells are in memory.

Comment: then how can i handle the situation ? if i initialise it in cell class it gets initialised 14 time. if i pass it as argument it replicates the selected time in all 14 fields?

Comment: Yes, *it gets initialised 14 times* but it gets deallocated when the cell goes off screen. You cannot use **one** picker for all cells.

Comment: it take 2 or more seconds or more to load that screen even without API call. that is real problem . this UI jerk is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting the code.

```
class "you class": UIViewController{

    lazy var fromDatePicker: UIDatePicker = {
         let fromDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        fromDatePicker.datePickerMode = .time
        fromDatePicker.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US") as Locale
        fromDatePicker.minuteInterval = 30
        if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
            fromDatePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
            
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
         return fromDatePicker
     }()
}
```